# Contradiction in Euler’s Identity? $2i\pi = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

Many of us know Euler’s famous identity:

> $e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0$.

But if we add -1 (subtract 1) to both sides we get:

> $e^{i\pi} = -1$

then natural log of both sides and:

> $i\pi = \ln(-1)$

Next we multiply both sides by 2:

> $2i\pi = 2\ln(-1)$

Which by basic logarithm rules is equal to:

> $2i\pi = \ln({-1}^2) = \ln(1) = 0$

so

> $2i\pi = 0$

which can’t be true as either 2, i or $\pi$ would have to equal 0. My best guess is that logarithms just plainly aren’t defined for negative values, I just assumed this was just true logarithms bounded under the real numbers, though I might be wrong. If someone could help it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Natural logarithm is for positive numbers, not complex numbers. Note that $e^{0}=e^{2\pi i}$ but $0 \neq 2\pi i$.

Comment: Yeah, and as said below, it is defined, but differently. Thanks.

Comment: What i mean is that the multi-valued logarithm in the complex plane is not called natural logarithm and properties of natural logarithm don't hold for it.

Comment: Right, I missed that in your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (complex) logarithm is a multivalued function. The solution to $$ e^{z} = w$$ is given by $$ z= \log w + 2\pi i n$$ where $n$ is an arbitrary integer, $n=\dots, -2,-1,0,1,2,\dots$.

In your case, you will get
$$ 2\pi i = 0 + 2\pi in$$ which is clearly no contradiction (as $n=1$ makes this an equality).

Comment: Could you please edit this so it gives a definitively answer... thanks

Comment: Thanks. That is better.

Comment: @L.McDonald If you feel it is a definitive answer then mark it with a $\color{green}\checkmark$

Comment: I know, but it was late at night for me, and I didn’t have time for the 10 minute break.